# Apply material / texture to each generated mesh geometry (face) individually

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, geometry-nodes, procedural

With geometry nodes, I generated a more complex mesh procedurally from the faces of an ico sphere by splitting edges.

Here is my node geo node setup:

[image: Geo Node Setup]

Now I wanted to apply a certain material, created with the shader graph to each individual one of these meshes generated from the faces.

Because the material is gonna be textured, it is important that each face carries the same texture by itself, not the generated "multi-mesh" of the Geometry Nodes as a whole.

The result I'm getting right now is this:

[image: Failed applied texture]

As you can see, the texture is being stretched over the whole mesh.

That is not what I want and I'm not sure how to go about it, logically I would have thought that "Set Material" would set a material for the extruded mesh in the steps before.

But that doesn't seem to be the case.

The result I would like to get would be something like this, of course Donald Duck would be on every single one of the "combs" on the left:

[image: What I would like to have]

Can you help me?

Also the material shader node setup for completeness:

[image: Material Shader]

(You might see, I also used the Attribute node. That did something else, but didn't solve the problem either.)

Here is the .blend file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/eilnks1bhsnixln/textureproblem.blend/file

Comment: @etlaM Do you mean you want this whole material not to be over the whole mesh, but you want this material to completely be on each face?

Comment: @etlaM could you attach a sample end result you want (any reference image or something)

Comment: @YousufChaudhry I added a sample picture for you :)